# Reacting accuracy: 0.0000e+00 in Keras Model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Below is my Keras model for trainding data sets with training_x set with 4 inputs with floats and training_y set with either 0 or 1. 
For the first epoch, it reaches accuracy about 3.6000e-05. 
Then it gives accuracy: 0.0000e+00 when the second epoch starts for the entire process. I am not how to fix it. Could you please give me some advice?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

from keras.layers import Dense

model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='selu', input_dim=4))

model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='selu'))

model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

CSV_FILE = "ddos.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILE)
df.loc[(df.Label == "ddos"), "Label"] = 1
df.loc[(df.Label == "Benign"), "Label"] = 0

x_train = np.array(df[["Flow Pkts/s", "Flow IAT Mean", "Flow IAT Max", "Flow IAT Min"]])
y_train = np.array(df[["Label"]])


# x_train and y_train are Numpy arrays --just like in the Scikit-Learn API.
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=128)
```

This is the output from epoch 2:

```
1991296/2000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 3.6157e-05
1994368/2000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 3.6102e-05
1998208/2000000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 3.6032e-05
2000000/2000000 [==============================] - 33s 17us/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 3.6000e-05
Epoch 2/100

    128/2000000 [..............................] - ETA: 25:27 - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
   3840/2000000 [..............................] - ETA: 1:17 - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 
   8064/2000000 [..............................] - ETA: 49s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 
  11776/2000000 [..............................] - ETA: 42s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
  16256/2000000 [..............................] - ETA: 36s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
  20096/2000000 [..............................] - ETA: 34s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: use `sigmoid` instead of softmax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your final activation function seems out of place.

  Usually, for binary classification problems with 1 output neuron, we use   `sigmoid` activation function instead of `softmax`.
- Try normalizing your data. Remove any `nan` or missing value in your dataframes.

```
x_train = (x_train - np.max(x_train))/(np.max(x_train) - np.min(x_train))
y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype = 'float32')
```

Make your `x` and `y`, `float32` instead of integers.

```
df.loc[(df.Label == "ddos"), "Label"] = 1.
df.loc[(df.Label == "Benign"), "Label"] = 0.
```

Comment: I tried both softmax and changing x and y to float32, but the outcome is still same.

Comment: Not softmax, I meant use sigmoid.

Comment: Can you print few rows of x_train and y_train?

Comment: `x_train : [18.365417,   55206.416667,     1566821.0,         167.0]
y_train: [0]`

This is my best. Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: Your data is highly skewed, you didn't normalize as I suggested, also your `y` is integer. Check the updated code and fix those.

Comment: Normalizing the data was the main solution to my problem. Thank you so much for your help.